# What should be the minimum width to make footer responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my site's footer responsive. I am using 400 px minimum width for the website to increase the height of the footer but it does not work. Please let me know how can I increase the height of the footer for small screens.

Here is the code,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px;) {
    #copyright {
        height:50px;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is my code,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #copyright {
        height:50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be max-width so you can target screens up to 400px width. With min-width you are telling to apply the css rule if the minimum width is 400px :)

http://jsfiddle.net/h42p5x0h/

```css
#copyright {
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
@media handheld,
only screen and (max-width: 400px),
only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
  #copyright {
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="copyright">Copyright<div>
```

Comment: I want to target small screen not big screens.

Comment: Well read what I wrote :) My example shows you how to target screens up to 400px :)

Comment: Make a fiddle with your code because this is working :) I am using it almost every day :)

Comment: That is not your full/source code :) You just changed what you had with max-width. There is something wrong with the rest of your html/css :)

Comment: I found the error. The height tag for the original width had !important tag with it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want your `#copyright` footer to be 50pixels high on small screens (ie : screen with a maximal width = 400px)

Then your CSS rule should be :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #copyright {
        height:50px;
    }
}
```

Be careful not having a  `;` in your media query

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oua2r21/)